# namedWindow is displaying, but not working

Tags: c++, opencv, mouseevent

I'm working on the program that will to draw a red point on the image by mouse. `

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv; 
using namespace std;

void CallBackFunc(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userdata)
{
    printf("Test");
    if (event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        printf("LBUTTON DOWN %d, %d \n", x, y);
        circle( (*(Mat*)userdata), Point(x, y), 2, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 3);
        imshow("img", *(Mat*)userdata);//ADDED
    }
    else if(event == EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        printf("RBUTTON DOWN %d, %d \n", x, y);
    }
    else if (event == EVENT_MBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        printf("MBUTTON DOWN %d, %d \n", x, y);
    }
    else if (event == EVENT_MOUSEMOVE)
    {
        printf("MOVE %d, %d \n", x, y);
    }

}

int main(int, char)
{
    namedWindow("img", 0);
    Mat img = imread("blank.jpg");
    setMouseCallback("img", CallBackFunc, &img);
    imshow("img", img);

    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Image is displaying correctly, but there are no information displayed in the console window and dots are not appearing on the image.
My code is based on the tutorial from link below:
https://youtu.be/iWCqjWTx-wI
EDIT: After adding the updating line in callback function program is still not working. The 'Test' isn't appearing in the command window. It can be problem with 'namedWindow' function. I'm working on Windows 7, Visual Studio 2015, OpenCV 3.3.1.

Comment: add a printf at the beginning of the callback function to test that the callback is working at all. After that find out why the callback func isnt called at all or why the events aren't set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updating the image in the window when you add a circle to it. You should do it in the callback function. I tried the following code and it works.

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void CallBackFunc(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userdata)
{
    if (event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        printf("LBUTTON DOWN %d, %d \n", x, y);
        circle((*(Mat*)userdata), Point(x, y), 2, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 3);
        imshow("img", *(Mat*)userdata); // ADDED
    }
    else if (event == EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        printf("RBUTTON DOWN %d, %d \n", x, y);
    }
    else if (event == EVENT_MBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        printf("MBUTTON DOWN %d, %d \n", x, y);
    }
    else if (event == EVENT_MOUSEMOVE)
    {
        printf("MOVE %d, %d \n", x, y);
    }

}

int main(int, char)
{
    namedWindow("img", 0);
    Mat img = imread("squares.png");
    setMouseCallback("img", CallBackFunc, &img);
    imshow("img", img);

    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an `imshow` in your `CallBackFunc` function. At the end of the `CallBackFunc`, you must add this line:

```
imshow("img", (*(Mat*)userdata));
```

Because the `imshow` in your main doesn't get the modification you do in `CallBackFunc`

Comment: Still nothing. I think it's a problem with namedWindow function, it's not working properly on my computer. Any suggestions regarding that?

Comment: @J.Majcher I tested your code with my modification and it works properly. Could you update your post please?

Comment: @J.Majcher again it works normally in my machine! Do you get LBUTTON DOWN printed in your terminal?

Comment: Nope :<
I'll try it on another computer.

Comment: @J.Majcher Okay then let me know